# After IORegisterForSystemPower failing to call IODeregisterForSystemPower

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, sleep

I have an application, written in Objective-C for MacOS 10.10+ which registers for sleep/wake notifications (code sample below, but the code isn't the question). What I am wondering is, if I call IORegisterForSystemPower at App initialisation, but during debugging I kill the app before it has a chance to call IODeregisterForSystemPower, what are the implications? Does the app get de-registered automatically when it dies in any case? Is there a system dictionary I need to clear out (a plist somewhere, etc.)? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
io_object_t                 root_notifier = MACH_PORT_NULL;
IONotificationPortRef       notify = NULL;

DebugLog(@"App: Logging IORegisterForSystemPower sleep/wake notifications %@", [NSDate date]);

/* Log sleep/wake messages */
powerCallbackPort = IORegisterForSystemPower ((__bridge void *)self, &notify, sleepWakeCallback, &root_notifier);
if ( powerCallbackPort == IO_OBJECT_NULL ) {
    DebugLog(@"IORegisterForSystemPower failed");
    return;
}

self.rootNotifierPtr = &(root_notifier);  // MARK: deregister with this pointer

if ( notify && powerCallbackPort )
{
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notify), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know the exact answer. But it may help you.

First of, if you call `IORegisterForSystemPower`, you need to make two calls in this order: - Call `IODeregisterForSystemPower` with the 'notifier' argument returned here. - Then call `IONotificationPortDestroy` passing the 'thePortRef' argument returned here ([Please visit apple's document for more detail](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1557114-ioregisterforsystempower?language=objc)).

In case of port binding, if I use `CFSocketSetAddress`, before releasing this socket no other can use this port for binding. But in case of app terminate/closed without releasing this socket this port is available. That means after terminated the app system automatically releasing this.

> Does the app get de-registered automatically when it dies in any case?

I think it will automatically de-registered by system.

I also used similar code as you in one of my project. But recently replaced with below codes:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(receiveWakeNotification:) name: NSWorkspaceDidWakeNotification object: nil];
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(receiveSleepNotification:) name: NSWorkspaceWillSleepNotification object: nil];
```